# Flask images not being saved or loading

Tags: python, html, image, flask, save

I am making a website and am trying to make a feature for each user to have an individual barcode, as well as a profile picture. But images aren't saving to my file and won't load on the site. Any help would be appreciated.
This is my code:

My function for saving a barcode as a image:

```
def save_barcode(barcode):
    form = RegistrationForm()
    current_user.username = form.username.data
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    f_ext = current_user.username
    barcode_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    barcode_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/barcodes', 'picture_fn')

    barcode.save(barcode_path)

    return barcode_fn
```

My function for saving a profile picture:

```
def save_picture(form_picture):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_picture.filename)
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/profile_pics', picture_fn)

    output_size = (125, 125)
    i = Image.open(form_picture)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(picture_path)

    return picture_fn
```

This is how I'm displaying both of these in html (image_file variable has been set to the result of the save_barcode or save_image functions):

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <img src="{{ image_file }}">
</div>
```

My routes where the `image_file` variable is initiated:

Barcode route:

```
    image_file = url_for('static', filename='barcodes/' + 
    current_user.barcode) 
    return render_template('barcode.html', title='My Barcode', 
    form=form, image_file=image_file)
```

Account route:

```
@app.route("/account", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():
   form = UpdateAccountForm()
   if form.validate_on_submit():
      if form.picture.data:
         picture_file = save_picture(form.picture.data)
      current_user.image_file = picture_file
      current_user.username = form.username.data
      current_user.email = form.email.data
      current_user.age = form.age.data
      db.session.commit()
      flash('Your account has been updated!', 'success')
      return redirect(url_for('account'))
   elif request.method == 'GET':
      form.username.data = current_user.username
      form.email.data = current_user.email
      form.age.data = current_user.age
   usage_calculator()
   image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + 
   current_user.image_file)
   temp_time = Usage.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).first()
   time_spent = temp_time.time_spent
   return render_template('account.html', title='Account', 
   image_file=image_file, form=form, time_spent=time_spent)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is that the functions `save_image()` and `save_barcode()` don't return a complete image path. The variable `image_file` holds the name of the image, not the complete path to it. To generate the complete path, you will need something similar to this in your route that displays the template with the image:

```
image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)
```

Comment: I've added this in now but it still doesn't work. Any other ideas on what to do?

Comment: Hmm, could you please edit your question to include the route that returns the html template in which you want the image displayed?

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back. I've edited my question to include these

Comment: Ok, thanks. Could you clarify which (if not both) of the two functions is not saving or returning a valid filename?

Comment: both of them aren't working

Comment: Do you know if the `user.image_file` is being correctly updated? As in, if you print out a user object before and after updating it, are you successfully able to edit user attributes?